# Document Update policy in Azure Search Service

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure Search Service that have an indexer using a SQL view stored in our DB as the data source. This view shows tickets for past 6 months. What I want is that this indexer should delete documents when my view gets updated every day (cause of CreateDateTime < 6 months). I use High watermark policy on column LastUpdatedTime. I think this policy will ensure updating document when corresponding row gets updated. BUT I am not sure when that row (support case) goes out of the view, will it result in document getting deleted.

I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in that when a row goes out of the view, the corresponding document doesn't get deleted by the indexer.

One way to do this would be to select some older documents (say, with a 2 week buffer) but mark older documents as stale in your view, then use [soft deletion policy feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#soft-delete-column-deletion-detection-policy) to delete those documents.

Comment: Hey Eugene. Thanks for the reply!
To use soft deletion policy feature, I think I would have to add a new column in the SQL view. I don't want to do that (I am consuming the view, can't change it). Is there a way to do this in Azure Search Service index itself?

Comment: Not that I know of. In the meantime, you can upvote [this suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/13792500-possibility-to-delete-documents-that-correspond-to) on UserVoice - that's the feature you might be looking for.